# Generating access token for Google Drive Service Account using only REST

Tags: google-drive-api, jwt, access-token

My goal is to obtain an `access_token` that I can use to make REST API calls against a Google Drive account. I need to be able to use a Google Service account since the underlying code takes place without any user interaction (server to server process).

I am currently able to generate a `credential.json` file using Google's Service Account UI. Passing this `credential.json` to a method in the Google .NET SDK gives me an authorization token.

What I would like to do is to take the values inside the `credential.json` ..

- type
- project_id
- private_key_id
- private_key
- client_email
- client_id
- auth_uri
- token_uri
- auth_provider_x509_cert_url
- client_x509_cert_url

and use them in a REST API call to obtain the access token. However, I cannot find the REST API endpoint that allows me to do this without having to built the JWT token manually.

Does such an API endpoint exist?

Comment: Have you tried to look up in the documentation about [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ - Yes I have. Google's recommendation is to use an SDK instead of building the JWT token manually. I am just hoping there is some other way to make a REST API call without having to manually create and sign the JWT. Google's SDK, for example, only requires the service account email and private key in order to gain access to Google Drive.